# C# EWS check if the user credentials are wrong or the service is just unreachable

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm using the EWS (2.2.1.0) and i need to read emails with my application for automate some tasks. 
I would like to show a warning message if the inserted credentials are wrong or, if the connection is missing, just display an error icon in the status bar.

I need to distinguish if the user credentials are wrong or just the connection is missing.
The problem is that the *AutodiscoverUrl()* method **in both cases** return the same *AutodiscoverLocalException*:

> The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.

This is weird and make no sense.

My code as follow:

```
    try
    {
        exService.TraceEnabled = true;
        exService.Credentials = new WebCredentials(UserSettings.Email.EmailAddress, UserSettings.Email.EmailPassword);
        exService.AutodiscoverUrl(UserSettings.Email.EmailAddress, (string redirectionUrl) => {
            bool result = false;
            Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

            if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
                result = true;

            return result;
        });
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(ApplicationSettings.General.WaitForNextConnectionRetry);
    }
```

Can someone explain me how to check if the user credentials are wrong or the service is just unreachable?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test Sample link: [Get started with EWS Managed API client applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/get-started-with-ews-managed-api-client-applications)

I think there is no good way to distinguish the user credential or Uri. For me, I just to add "try catch" to detect the error. Also, I tested the sample code above and provide a wrong pwd. Then the error occurred in service.AutodiscoverUrl line. Please see the trace messsage:

[image]

Or maybe we can get the Trace message to detect it.

Comment: I solved the issue using a custom ITraceListener that parse the various error messages.